# WAMP or XAMPP alternative that has Imagick already included

Tags: xampp, wamp, imagick

Recently lost my hard drive where I had WAMP installed and Imagick working.
Someone else did that part for me way back.
Reinstalling Win7 and getting everything working again = nightmare.
So I installed the latest version of WAMP - NO Imagick.
3 days of trying all the solutions on this site (and some others - sorry) and got nowhere.
Does anyone know of a "one shot" installation that will work out the box?
Maybe a fork of one of them - I looked but found nothing
Or maybe I should install Ubuntu onto an old PC and use that as a web server on my home LAN?
Seriously - they are depreciating the GD library some time soon and Imagick is apparently the successor but no-one supports Imagick natively.
Jumping through all sorts of hoops is no guarantee that it will work either as I have painfully found out.
Thanks in advance people.

Comment: Certainly software installation is easier and opens less security threads on Linux compared to MS-Windows. But that does not mean that you will save time, since you have to get used to the Linux environment which is a non trivial task for someone used to the MS-Windows eco system. I'd always say: analyse and solve the issue at hand instead of wildly trying out all alternatives you have heard of. You should understand and control your tools, not the other way 'round.

Comment: True - but paying someone to set up Ubuntu properly with a server and the file access from Win, take an image and then I carry on - I can restore the server at any time, pull off my code and when Win does it 6 monthly collapse, at least its simple to get earning again - To be honest, the only reason I use Windows is because I need to test in Internet Explorer. Does not get away from the fact that Wamp + XAMPP have turned into "only for power user" tools.

Comment: Sorry, I don't buy the reason that you use MS-Windows "only to test in Internet Explorer". That could be done by using a VM or their online test service. And if you want to pay for the setup, then you could much easier pay someone to setup the combination of apache, php and some database server on your system. I wonder what you _real_ reason is, _but_ that obviously is your private thing, not connected to the issue here. So I suggest you ask your question over at the SuperUser sister page, you are more likely to get an answer there. You can see the link at the bottom of this page in the footer

Comment: That is the primary reason whether you believe it or not - but the original question was "is there an alternative to WAMP or XAMPP that has Imagick capabilities in its un-tweaked standard installation" - sorry but I am here to get information, not to argue.

Answer (score 0):

WAMP and XAMPP are not up to speed with the transition from the soon to be removed GD library to the ImageMagic library and it would seem that neither are planning to bring their products up to date any time soon.
That leaves many users with a major problem as most web site developers need to be able to manipulate images at some time or another during their work.
For users who are not at a reasonably high level of expertize as far as messing around in the guts of the (in my case, Windows) operating systems, this is a nightmare and can be downright dangerous.
I did find what seemed to be a viable alternative in **WampDeveloper Pro** but unless you specifically go looking for it, their website is very hush-hush about the fact that its going to cost you over $125 to get it working.
You only find out about this at the first run after installing.

> So my options are the following:

- Put one of the Ubuntu distributions on a VM
  or
- Find an old drive, install it into your PC and make the PC dual boot using a Ubuntu distribution.

  The second option will "ease" me into converting from Microsoft based OS reliance to a Linux based OS however if that does not work out, I do have the option to create an Ubuntu VM under the Windows system (I have used VM for a while under Windows) and use that in place of the other Windows based web server alternatives.

> Either way I will be able to carry on servicing my clients and making a living without spending money or having a stroke due to pure frustration.

I may regret this decision BUT I may start wondering to myself "Now why did you wait so long?"